# Funcionamiento de ConfigureWebHostDefaults

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Esta es la firma para el método **ConfigureWebHostDefaults** de la clase **GenericHostBuilderExtensions** [sourceCode](https://github.com/aspnet/MetaPackages/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore/GenericHostBuilderExtensions.cs)

```
public static IHostBuilder ConfigureWebHostDefaults(this IHostBuilder builder, Action<IWebHostBuilder> configure);
```

Luego su uso en el método **CreateHostBuilder** de la clase **Program** lo invoca de la siguiente forma:

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
```

el parámetro de entrada "webBuilder" tiene la opción de auto llenado; pregunto

1. ¿Estas opciones de dónde vienen?
2. ¿Es el framework el que ya sabe como traer estas opciones o existe algún método que yo me estoy perdiendo?
3. ¿Se ha definido en alguna parte el Action delegate que ingresa al método?

[image: Opciones de llenado]

Answer (score 2):

El método ConfigureWebHostDefaults Configura una interfaz [IHostBuilder](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) con valores predeterminados para alojar una aplicación web.

Los siguientes valores predeterminados se aplican a IHostBuilder :

- Utilizar Kestrel como servidor web y configurarlo utilizando los proveedores de configuración de la aplicación.
- Configurar WebRootFileProvider para incluir activos web estáticos de proyectos a los que hace referencia el ensamblado de entrada durante el desarrollo
- Agrega el middleware HostFiltering
- Agrega el middleware ForderedHeaders si ASPNETCORE_FORWARDEDHEADERS_ENABLED = true,
- Habilitar la integración de IIS

Comment: dónde están definidos estos "valores predeterminados" que asumo es el listado de opciones que se despliegan con webBuilder?. Veo que "IHostBuilder" posee una propiedad "Properties"  de tipo "IDictionary" pero no logro encontrar en el código fuente la implemetación de "IHostBuilder" que me pueda generar el listado de opciones para el "webBuilder"